# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

> If $f_n(x) = n^{-x}x^n\cos(nx)$ defines the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Does the sequence of function  converge uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Should I just do the pointwise convergence, and then determine the uniform convergence by evaluating $M_n:= \sup \{ |f_n(x) - f(x)| \}$?

If taking the path of pointwise convergence, I get stuck with $f_n(1)$ as it leaves me with $\cos(n)$ on the RHS.

Thank you.

**My work**

$f_n(0) = 0$, $f_n(1) = 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ (using L'Hospital's Rule).

Then, $M_n := \sup\{|f_n(x) - f(x)|: x \in [0,1]\} = \max \{\frac{x^n\cos(nx)}{n^x}; 0 \le x \le 1\}$

$f_n'(x) = 0\Rightarrow x = 0$; so $M_n = f_n(0) = 0 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, obviously.

Therefore as $M_n \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$ we can conclude that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is not $\cos(nx)$ which is uniformly bounded by $1$, but the behaviour of the product $x^n\cdot n^{-x}$ near $0^+$ and $1^-$.

Hint. Note that if $x\in[0,1/2]$ then
$$|f_n(x)|=\frac{x^n|\cos(nx)|}{n^x}\leq x^n\leq \frac{1}{2^n}.$$
On the other hand if $x\in[1/2,1]$ then
$$|f_n(x)|=\frac{x^n|\cos(nx)|}{n^x}\leq \frac{1}{n^x}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: but what would be the justification for that split of [0, 1/2] and [1/2, 1]? Is it because we have  component of cos in our function?

Comment: You have a problem at $f_n(1)$?, Then separate difficulties by considering $[0,1]$ as the union of $[0,r]$ and $[r,1]$ with $r$ any number in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Actually the problem is not $\cos(nx)$ which is uniformly bounded. The problem is the product $x^n$ and $n^{-x}$ and its behaviour near $0^+$ and $1^-$.

Comment: But when we do the pointwise of $f_n$ ,then at x = 1 $f_n(1) = (1)^nn^{-1}cos(1n) = (1)(1/n)(cos(n)$; unless I'm missing something obvious ...

Comment: Yes $f_n(1)=\cos(n)/n$ and by taking the limit as $n\to+\infty$, it goes to $0$. So the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ at $x=1$ is $0$.

Comment: Oh! sorry, that was my bad then. Then, according to that $f_n(1) \to 0$, right?

Comment: Yes! BTW, following my hint $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. What about the uniform convergence?

Comment: Well, for the uniform convergence I was going to use $M_n := \sup \{ |f_n(x) - f(x)\}$ where $f(x) = lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$

Comment: Since $f=0$, my hint should be useful ;-)

Comment: Yes, I added the answer below. Hopefully I did it right this time! :) Thanks

Comment: First of all you should add you tentative answer under your question (not as a separate answer). It is not true that $f'_n(x)=0$ implies that $x=0$. 
By my hint $\sup\{|f_n(x) - f(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}\leq \max(1/\sqrt{n},1/2^n)\to 0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69792/discussion-between-isuckatmathpleasehelpme-and-robert-z).